# problem of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be different nonempty sets, $X$ is compact and $Y$ is closed; show that there exist $a'∈ X$ and $b'∈ Y$ such that $|a'- b'|≤|a-b|$ for all $a ∈ X$ and $b ∈ Y$.

Comment: Are these subsets of the reals?

Comment: $b \in Y$ instead of $y \in Y$?

Comment: sorry, b belongs to Y

Answer (score 1):

If $X\cap Y\neq \phi$ then nothing to prove.

Let $X\cap Y= \phi$ as $Y$ is closed so $X\cap Y= \phi\implies d(x,Y)\neq 0$

Consider the function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R ;f(x)=d(x,Y)$  where $d(x,Y)=inf\{d(x,y):y\in Y\}$ $f$ is a continuous  mapping from a compact set hence $f(X)$ is compact and hence closed and bounded.So $\exists a\in X$ such that $f(a)=inf\{d(x,Y):x\in X\}=d(X,Y)\leq d(x,y) \forall x\in X,y \in Y$

So $d(a,Y)\leq d(x,y) \forall x\in X,y \in Y$.Again by definition of $d(a,Y),\exists b\in Y$ such that $d(a,b)\leq d(x,y)\forall  x\in X,y \in Y$
Thus we find $a\in X,b\in Y$

NOTE:the above problem holds in a metric space .In this case the metric space is $\mathbb R$ with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

Consider $$d=\inf\{|x-y|\colon x\in X,y\in Y\}$$ and show that it is reachable, i.e. $|a'-b'|=d$ for some $a'\in X$ and $b'\in Y$

Comment: for serving that X is compact and Y is closed